# Transferring a data source from aspx to aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I was just wondering how I would program this datasource in aspx.vb, the code behind this web page.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="partsUsed" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [fact_parts_used] WHERE [parts_used_id] = @parts_used_id"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [fact_parts_used] ([wo_id], [part_id], [quantity]) VALUES (@wo_id, @part_id, @quantity)"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT * FROM 
                        (SELECT parts_used_id, dim_users.[user_name], full_name, 
                        wo_id as tasks, wo_id,
                        fact_parts_used.part_id, dim_parts.part_number+' '+ dim_parts.part_desc as Part, quantity, cost 
                        FROM fact_parts_used
                            INNER JOIN dim_users ON dim_users.[user_id] = fact_parts_used.[user_id]
                            INNER JOIN dim_parts ON dim_parts.part_id = fact_parts_used.part_id
                        ) a
                    WHERE wo_id is not null AND tasks = wo_id"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [fact_parts_used] SET [part_id] = @part_id, [quantity] = @quantity, cost = @cost WHERE [parts_used_id] = @parts_used_id" 
    >
    <SelectParameters>

    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="parts_used_id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="part_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="parts_used_id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="wo_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="part_id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="quantity" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Questions posted on Stack Overflow should always show your research effort (what you've tried so far). See the Help Center article "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" (especially the "search and research section."  Have you made any attempt on your own to implement the datasource / databinding in code behind?

Comment: It looks like you are having a rough start on the site.  If I were you, I would take some time to read through the articles on the Help Center ("help" link at the top of the page), at least [the "asking" section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  Then you can go back and edit your questions to improve them  You've asked three questions so far, all with formatting problems, and all with other issues (reposting a question due to lack of answers, not showing your research effort, etc).